# Parameter undefined in javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, undefined

I can't solve the problem in this code that give me an undefined result for the parameter menu1 in the function 'table', called in the function menu().

```
function table(menu1){
var x=document.getElementById('myTable').rows
var y=x[0].cells
y[0].innerHTML = menu1; 
}
function menu(){
var tx =" some text ...";
table(tx);
}
```

It always return the value 'undefined' for menu1.

Please help!!!

Comment: You're missing a semicolon on line 2 and 3 (not that that matters so much), other than that; could you post your HTML?

Comment: both functions don't have any `return` statement, what do you mean when you say "It always return the value 'undefined' for menu1." ?

Comment: That bit works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/fvdxaz1d/ How are you calling `menu`?